# Perl Module install to mentioned directory

Tags: perl, module, installation

I want to install a Perl module to a particular directory which I am mentioning while executing a command.

I want this module to be installed in a mentioned path.

Command I tried is

```
$ env PERL_MM_OPT='INSTALL_BASE=/home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts' cpanm Log::Log4perl
```

But this by default installed in `/home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts/lib/perl5`.

What could be the reason? How to install the module in particular directory which I am mentioning?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation of [INSTALL_BASE](https://perldoc.pl/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.html#INSTALL_BASE). You seem to be interested in changing just the `INSTALLPRIVLIB` path. Maybe you want to set the `LIB` attribute only, described in the next section?